# Implied in the description

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was kind of perplexed by this expression. I came up with it while listening to the describtion of some concenpt:

> //description of something
>
> Of course, implied in this description is
>   the fact that ...

I'm used to say that something implies ***from*** something. Is it incorrect and we say that something implies ***in*** something?

Comment: You can understand the sentence as saying : " The fact that [...] is implied in this description". Or "something is implied in this description, this something is the fact that [...]".  It means that we understand  "The fact that [...]" without it being explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word order in the sentence has been changed probably for emphasis. The sentence could be rephrased to:

> Of course, the fact that ... is **implied** in this description"

The preposition "in" is used to go with the noun phrase "this description" and it has nothing to do with the verb to imply. To imply is a transitive verb which means:

> Indicate the truth or existence of (something) by suggestion rather
>   than explicit reference

To imply is not used as an intransitive verb and "something implies from something" is not a grammatical construction as the verb doesn't take an object . It should be "something (the fact) is implied in something (this description)" or "he/she/they, etc. implied something (the fact) in something (this description)".